# Cosa vuol dire "spizzare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Ogni volta che Rocco accompagnava a casa il padre, Venera lo **spizzava** dietro le tende della finestra – lasciando cadere la cortina appena realizzava che lui l’aveva notata. Rocco portava la mano alla falda del cappello e accennava un inchino.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "spizzare" in questo brano? Ho trovato questo verbo in parecchi dizionari, ma tutte le accezioni fanno riferimento a giochi di carte, al calcio o al biliardo.

Comment: Qui sembra abbia il significato di sbirciare, guardare di nascosto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo [blog di dialetto romanesco](https://www.google.com/amp/s/siportaaroma.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/ssi-porta-a-roma-il-glossario-pseudo-romanesco-parte-1-verbi-base/amp/) si può leggere:

> **Spizzare**
>
> v.tr. [sogg-v-arg] – è il mio preferito. Nessuno dà pizze in faccia,
>   i pestaggi lasciamoli fare ai neofasciti. “Ahò, quello sta a spizzà a
>   Tatiana”.  Approfonditi studi etimologici da me condotti hanno
>   dimostrato scientificamente che è una trasfusione semantica dal gioco
>   delle carte. **Qui si tratta di uno sguardo provocatore, sottecchi,
>   nascosto ma non troppo, come quando si scoprono le carte de poker.**
>   Tatiana, nonostante sia tarchiata e francamente bruttarella, in questa
>   occasione è stata oggetto di sguardi interessati alla sua fisicità.

Viene data al termine un’interpretazione corrispondente al guardare di nascosto, di sottecchi, sbirciare.

Comment: È un modo di guardare che può essere nascosto ma in ogni caso è attento, non veloce o superficiale.